# Python 3.3 vs Python 3.2 issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Don't know if this is a bug or not, but my script no longer works on Python 3.3 while it works fine on Python 3.2.

I have a generator function to return bytes from a binary file like so:

```
def yield_record(infile, size = 1):

    while True:
        block = infile.read(size)

        if len(block) == 0:
            break
        else:

            yield (block[0], block[1:])
```

My issue

With Python 3.2, the type of block[0] is 'int' and the type of block[1:] is 'bytes'.  This is as expected.

With Python 3.3, the type of block[0] is 'str' and the type of block[1:] is also 'str'.  This is not expected and causes the code receiving the data to fail.

Anyone know what is up?

Here is the code that uses the generator.

```
with open(infilename, mode='rb') as trace_stream:
    # create an empty list of trace records
    trace = []
    record_count = 0

    # iterate over each record in the binary stream
    for record_type, record_data in yield_record(trace_stream,
                                                 size=RECORD_LENGTH):
        record_count += 1

        try:
            # determine what class this record belongs to
            record_class = RECORD_CLASS[record_type]
            # instantiate the new record
            new_record = record_class(record_data)
            # append this new record to our trace
            trace.append(new_record)

        except KeyError as err:
            print("Unhandled Record Type: {0}  Record: {1}".format(record_type, record_count))
```

Thanks,

Here is a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: With my installation of Python 3.3.2 (Win7 x64), `block[0]` is still an `int`, `block[1:]` is a `bytes` object.

Comment: Are you 100% certain you are still opening `trace_stream` as binary? Your problem is only reproducible when using files opened in text mode.

Comment: As a general suggestion: *Never post screenshots of textual data!*.
You can copy-paste the text from the console. In this way other people can copy what you typed, people searching from google might find a match with the code you are typing etc. Using images is just a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: As for the O.P. own answer, bellow, the question was made by mistake - he was running Python 2.7 instead of 3.3

Answer (score 1):

OK I discovered the problem.  For some reason when I ran it the first time from the command line I thought the Python3.3 interpreter was running, since that is the first one in my path, but the Python 2.7 interpreter must have run instead.  When I gave the full path to the python3.3 interpreter, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. In my Python 3.3.2 installation (Win7 x64), `bytes` object slicing works just the way it always has:

```
>>> b"1234"[0]
49
```

However

```
>>> "1234"[0]
'1'
```

So, you're probably not opening your file in binary mode.

Comment: I am using the identical script, running under both interpreters.  As shown above it is opening in read-binary mode.  Like you I am on Windows 7-64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
while True:
    block = infile.read(size)
    assert isinstance(block[0], int)
```

And follow the traceback. You'll see the file is being opened in text mode somewhere